# How to handle time out error in better_player of flutter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter

I try to use [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) for the cache strategy of videos. When I want to load a large video from the network with slow connections, I get this error `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: The request timed out., null, null)`. But when I use video_player to load, it works correctly. Can you edit `BetterPlayer.m` files to handle large videos without that error?

I tried with these codes but they are not fixed:

```
item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    NSTimeInterval bufferingTime = 280.0;
    [item setPreferredForwardBufferDuration:bufferingTime];
}
```